XState Typegen is incomplete when creating separate objects for states
As my state machine definition is growing, I decided to move substates into separate objects in separate files.
It's now looking like this:
const myMachine = createMachine({
 ...
 states: {
  initial: {
  ...
  states: {
   substate: { ...SUB_STATE },
  }
 }
}

In separate files:
export const SUB_STATE: StateNodeConfig<MyContext, any, MyEvent, BaseActionObject> = {
 type: "parallel",
 states: {
  subsubstate1: { ...SUB_SUB_STATE_1 },
  subsubstate2: { ...SUB_SUB_STATE_2 }
 }
}

SUB_SUB_STATE_1 and SUB_SUB_STATE_2 are also of type StateNodeConfig.
It's working fine, but the TypeScript typegen doesn't recognize the sub-states which results in errors referencing a substate in a react component.
The matchesStates property of the typegen.ts File looks like this:
matchesStates: "initial" | "initial.substate" | { "initial"?: "substate"; };
state.matches("initial.substate.subsubstate1.xyz") will result in the error "No Overload Matches This Call".
What can I do to make the typegen understand the nested state config?
I'm currently using XState 4.38.2
Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jmrvnd?file=src%2Fstate-machine.tsx
